# Запомнить где остановился итератор при предыдущем запуске скрипта

Tags: php

Необходимо выполнить перебор файлов. Для этого использую:

```
$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($rootPath));
// где $rootPath - директория, в которой нужно перебрать файлы
```

Каким образом запомнить где остановился итератор при предыдущем запуске скрипта? Нужно чтобы файлы которые уже перебирались не участвовали в новом переборе

P.S. Можно использовать другой способ перебора, главное чтобы он был рекурсивный

Comment: Да как всегда: скинуть в файл, БД или memcache/аналог. Если разово, то достаточно и файла, если нет - возможно, история в БД будет полезна.

Comment: Что скинуть в файл?